# Mapping Json into nested POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've the following JSON from some upstream api

```
{
    "Id": "",
    "Name": "",
    "Age": ""
}
```

And I need to map this above json to a downstream request paylaod (POJO) .

```
public class Employee
{
     @JsonProperty("Id")
     private Integer Id;
     private User user;
}

public class User {

     @JsonProperty("Name")
     private String name;

     @JsonProperty("Age")
     private String age;

}
```

Right now I'm doing something like

```
Employee employee = new ObjectMapper().treeToValue(JsonNode node,Employee.class);
```

But this is giving null in User Object.

The challenge here is , that the json we are getting from upstream can't be changed . So , is there is any way to map the fields into the nested **User** object , without changing the structure of json received from upstream.

**One Solution is** : map the fields separately into User object and then set it into the Employee object . But that's not an efficient solution , because for null validations we would need to do validations separately for User and Employee objects. If the nesting is complex then , validation will be hell of replicated code .

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON does not comply with your `Employee` class.

Because `name` and `age` is at the same level as `id`, but you want to wrapped in a class `User`.

So either:

1. Change the json the structure to

   ```
    {
     "id": "", 
     "user": {
       "name": "", 
       "age": ""
      }
    }
   ```

Or

2. Unwrap the User class, the Employee class will be:

   ```
    public class Employee
    {
        @JsonProperty("Id")
        private Integer Id;

        @JsonProperty("Name")
        private String name;

        @JsonProperty("Age")
        private String age;
    }
   ```

**Edit**

If you can't choose either option 1 or 2, you have only one option left is to create custom deserializer:

Write a deserializer:

```
public class EmployeeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 

    public EmployeeDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public EmployeeDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public Employee deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        int id = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("Id")).numberValue();
        String name = node.get("Name").asText();
        String age = node.get("Age")).asText();
        User user = new User(name, age);
        return new Employee(id, user);
    }
}
```

Then register this deserializer:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Employee.class, new EmployeeDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

Employee readValue = mapper.readValue(json, Employee.class);
```

Another way to register deserializer is:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = EmployeeDeserializer.class)
public class Employee {
```

Comment: json received from upstream can't be changed . So , is there is any way to map the fields into the nested User object , without changing the structure of json received from upstream.

Comment: You can't change to option 2?

Comment: yup , can't change to option 2 , because the request payload for the downstream has a definite structure to which i need to conform .

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not nesting your JSON correctly. Or your Object Structure is wrong.

JSON should be:

```
{
    "Id": "",
    "user" : {
                "Name": "",
                "Age": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: json received from upstream can't be changed . So , is there is any way to map the fields into the nested User object , without changing the structure of json received from upstream.

Answer (score 0):

The json structure does not match the structure of your classes.
if the json was like;

```
{
  "Id": "an-id,
  "user": {
    "Name": "Joe",
    "Age": "21"
  }
}
```

Then your code to deserialise to an Employee object would work.

Comment: json received from upstream can't be changed . So , is there is any way to map the fields into the nested User object , without changing the structure of json received from upstream.

Comment: I would always try to match my class structure to the JSON format I want. So your best option here is to have two Employee classes, with appropriate names, one that matches the incoming JSOn and one that matches the downstream JSON, then have a mapper class that maps one to the other, that is not used for serializing or deserializing. Custom Serialization code is usually unnecessary and messy